# How can I POST JSON values without property expansion in soapUI?

Tags: json, post, properties, parameters, soapui

In soapUI, I am trying to perform an HTTP POST with the following JSON:

```
{
   "myNode":{
      "myOtherNode":"${MY_VALUE}"
   }
}
```

The POST operation is successful, but in the response the value for `myOtherNode` is blank. I'm guessing this is because soapUI is treating it as parameter and trying to replace it. I do not want it replaced; I want to send it as it is.

I am able to do the same thing using command line curl.

Edit: I could not find the answer in their [Property Expansion Documentation](http://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/property-expansion.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the property expansion from replacing `${MY_VALUE}` you can add an extra $ like this:

```
{
   "myNode":{
      "myOtherNode":"$${MY_VALUE}"
   }
}
```

Doing that your original json will be sent like this:

```
{
   "myNode":{
      "myOtherNode":"${MY_VALUE}"
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I just found the answer on their forum here:
http://forum.soapui.org/viewtopic.php?t=12537#p53381
There doesn't seem to be anything on their official documentation on parameters though.